# I am trying to display an image in a relative path in a window using OpenCV, but I get a Type Error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, os.path

Obviously the error message is a Type Error, but when I print it the output is "***None***".

I looked for an error because it is not a Numpy array, so I converted it to a Numpy array.

Also, I tried to imread a variable with relative or absolute paths.

```py
Img_Folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Photo', 'GMD Miss')
File_List = os.listdir(Img_Folder)

img = Img_Folder + File_List[0]
img = np.array(img)
img = cv2.imread(img)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thus, I got this error message.

> TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mat'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code. The main one (that the question is about) comes from the line: `img = np.array(img)`. You are building a *np* array out of the file path (**which makes no sense**), and you pass that to *imread*.

You should:

- Check:

  - [[OpenCV.Docs]: Image file reading and writing - imread()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56)
  - [[OpenCV 2.Docs]: User interface](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#user-interface) for other functions that you use
- Print any variable in your code when you have doubts, or something doesn't work. That will save you a lot of time, and will also enable you to solve lots of issues yourself
- Remove the aforementioned line from your code

**Example**:

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>> import cv2
> >>>
> >>> img_file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..\\..\\c", "2160-0.jpg")
> >>> img_file_name  # Make sure that the path contains all the path separators (which doesn't happen in your case, as the last one is missing, because of: `img = Img_Folder + File_List[0]`)
> 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\..\\..\\c\\2160-0.jpg'
> >>>
> >>> img = cv2.imread(img_file_name)
> >>> type(img), img.shape
> (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (316, 647, 3))
> >>>
> >>> cv2.imshow("Image", img)
> >>> cv2.waitKey(0)  # Capital K
> >>>
> >>> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> >>>
> ```